# There was some issues with angular dependency conflicts then i delete node_modules folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'H:\All_Files\Scripts\Angular\example\node_modules\source-map\source-map.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry

Comment: now app is not working after re-install npm install

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing `npm install`, if that solves the issue you can move ahead. If not, then yes you should delete both `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`. Then rerun the `npm install`